# Reporting information using syslog

Tags: c, logging, syslog

I am trying to write a function which will take a priority level and a variable amount of strings as arguments to log information in an application.

The function looks something like this so far:

```
int _logf(int priority, char *fmt, ...)
{
    if (log.priority >= priority) {
        syslog(priority,  "LOG:%s", fmt);
    }
    /* stderr and syslog */
}
```

`log.priority` is an `int` set at run time which could be `LOG_INFO` / `LOG_DEBUG` / `LOG_ERR`

and in use:

```
_logf(LOG_INFO, "Starting app version %s", "1.0");
```

Is this an acceptable way to send log messages to `syslog`?

Comment: Where is the variable `log` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you do not involve the variable number of parameters possibly passed into your function.

On how to do this you might take a look a the following example using `vsyslog()`:

```
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdarg.h> 

...

int _logf(int priority, const char * fmt, ...)
{
  if (log.priority >= priority) 
  {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);

    vsyslog(priority, fmt, ap);

    va_end(ap);
  }
}
```

Then call it for example like so:

```
_logf(LOG_INFO, "LOG %s:%d (%s) - %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, "Just some info.");
```

---

**Update:**

To additionally log to `stderr` you might like to look ath function `vfprintf()`.