# How to find __FUNCTION__, __LINE__ and __FILE__ of parent function?

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I just made a fool of myself: I wanted to trace the execution of a process, and in order to do this, I had written a function `trace()`, which contains the following line of code:

```
printf("%s[%s:%d], %s\n", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, s_message);
```

I hoped to see in which function I was, what file and what line within that file, but I just saw that information of the file where I programmed that `trace()` function.

Is it possible, is there some `#define` or so, to tell the C compiler to take the mentioned macros from the parent of the calling function?

Comment: make `trace()` a macro.

Comment: Making `trace` a macro would be the obvious solution. If you don't know how, read how macros work and are defined. And don't spam tags! C++ is not C!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18658873/694576

Comment: BTW, the correct spelling as foreseen by the C standard is `__func__`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a macro, e.g.:

```
void _trace(char const *function, 
            char const *file, 
            long line, 
            char const *message) 
{
    printf("%s[%s:%ld], %s\n", function, file, line, message);
}

#define trace(message) _trace(__FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (message))
```

Comment: This is one of the really important uses of macros.

Comment: Since in some cases `__LINE__` can expand to a `long`, the type for the `line` parameter should be `long` and the format should be `"%ld"`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Good point, edited. I guess if `int` is 16 bits, this is something to keep in mind. Especially generated code can easily hit 32k loc per file. I guess it could be made `unsigned` too, actually.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, you should have a macro for that.
The reason for this is that all 3 used macros get expanded at pre-processing stage of compilation, and they will be replaced by the corresponding information, as it is encountered. That's the reason your actual output is where the `trace()` is implemented.

You could change your current `trace()` implementation to receive `const char *` for function name, file, and line. Then, have a macro, say `mTrace`, that expands to calling the initial trace function, passing exactly `__FUNCTION__,__FILE__, __LINE__`. Of course, your `mTrace` could get another parameter, the actual message you want to add, and pass it further to `trace()`.